# method is not a recognised objective c method

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, react-native, react-native-native-module

Lot of question are asked regarding the same but none of them solve my error.

Here is my objective c file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(LanguageTranslationModule, NSObject)


RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(callbackMethod:(NSString*)englishText (RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback)

@end
```

Here is my swift class

```
@objc(LanguageTranslationModule)
class LanguageTranslationModule: NSObject {

  var resultCallback: RCTResponseSenderBlock!

  @objc func callbackMethod(_ englishText: String, callback: @escaping RCTResponseSenderBlock) -> Void {
    resultCallback = callback
    debugPrint("Hi there")
    translateText(msg: englishText)
  }...
```

Here is my JS call from React Native

```
LanguageTranslationModule.callbackMethod(englishText, (err, r) => {
        if (!err) {
          setProgress(false);
          setMarathiText(r.text.toString());
        } else {
          setProgress(false);
          setMarathiText(err);
        }
      });
```

Following is my translate text method

```
func translateText(msg: String) {

    let options = TranslatorOptions(sourceLanguage: .en, targetLanguage: .mr)
    let englishMarathiTranslator = NaturalLanguage.naturalLanguage().translator(options: options)

    let conditions = ModelDownloadConditions(
      allowsCellularAccess: false,
      allowsBackgroundDownloading: true
    )

    englishMarathiTranslator.downloadModelIfNeeded(with: conditions) {error in
      guard error == nil else { return }
      englishMarathiTranslator.translate(msg) { (translatedText, error) in
        guard error == nil, let translatedText = translatedText else { return }
        let resultsDict = [
          "text" : translatedText
        ];
        self.resultCallback([NSNull() ,resultsDict])
      }
    }
  }
```

have added underscore to my first parameter in swift file as that is most of the solution to other questions asked on stack as well as there is space between the underscore and actual variable name. If I remove the englishText variable from all the files and hardcode that text in swift file then my function works fine. of course then I had to add underscore to the callback variable, so no logical error from my side

Comment: Don't you need to call callback inside your swift method? Your js method never triggered if you don't call.

Comment: @ibrahimyilmaz I have called it. look in the swift code

Comment: `resultCallback = callback` here you just assign it to another variable. Where have you called?

Comment: You need to call like `callback([NSNull(), [ "success" : true ]])`.

Comment: @ibrahimyilmaz I have called that code inside translateText method which is called inside callbackMethod. Check my code again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that the error is in the title of the question. It seems that your Swift method's signature doesn't match the signature declared in the Objective C interface.

Try adding an argument label to the second parameter in the declaration.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(LanguageTranslationModule, NSObject)


RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(callbackMethod:(NSString*)englishText callback:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback)
//                                                      ^^^^^^^^

@end
```

Explanation:

```
RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(callbackMethod:(NSString*)englishText callback:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback)
```

matches

```
@objc func callbackMethod(_ englishText: String, callback: @escaping RCTResponseSenderBlock) -> Void
```

while your original variant

```
RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(callbackMethod:(NSString*)englishText (RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback)
```

would match

```
@objc func callbackMethod(_ englishText: String, _ callback: @escaping RCTResponseSenderBlock) -> Void
```